# MATLAB asking for 444P codec for .avi file

Tags: matlab

I'm using a code that was working for a lot of `.avi` files. But now I ran it in a different data set and at some file I got the following error :

```
Error using VideoReader/init (line 457)
The file requires the following codec(s) to be installed on your system:
    444P

Error in VideoReader (line 146)
            obj.init(fileName);

Error in processVideo(line 19)
vidObj = VideoReader(filePath);
```

I have k-lite codec pack installed on 64-bit Windows 7. How should I work this around?

Thanks for any help

Comment: what file format are you trying to read? You gotta find that codec, I googled it and found some results, you might try google for a better solution.

Comment: They are all .avi files. I also Googled but could not find a reliable source. Can anyone reccomend a way to install this codec, without messing up my PC :)